# Files disappeared after being renamed using file.rename

Tags: r

I tried to use R to rename csv files in a folder with a loop. One of the parameters used in the process was the unique value of a column of a csv file after being imported as a data frame, which I misspecified (I misspelled "Reporter.ISO" as "ReporterISO"). After running the loop, there are only some of the files left in the folder. I want to know where the disappeared files went.

```
setwd([some folder])
versions= c("1992", "1996", "2002", "2007", "2012", "2017", "2022")
names(versions) = c("H0", "H1", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6")
files = list.files()

for (i in files){
  df = read.csv(i)
  reporter = tolower(unique(df$Reporter.ISO))
  v = versions[unique(df$Classification)]
  to = paste0("imports_2007_", reporter, "_hs6_v", v, ".csv")
  file.rename(i, to)
}
```

Are there any history of what R did that I could find or something similar?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it is difficult to say without knowing the data but one possible clue might be found if you print `to` and check for repetition.

Comment: One reason could be, some of your files had the same `Reporter.ISO` and `Classification` and thus got the same name. Probably you have overwritten it several times. If you have not done much in this directory since the incident, you have a chance to recover the data with an undelete tool.

Comment: I agree with @D.J, impossible to help without reproducible sample data/files. My gut feel is that `reporter` and `v` are vectors of size > 1. For example, consider `versions[c("H3", "H4")]` and what that means for constructing `to`. `file.rename` is vectorised in `i` and `to`, but both arguments must have the same length. I recommend including `print` statements to inspect `reporter` and `v`.

Comment: `file.rename()` is a low-level program and really dangerous, if you don't know exactly what you are doing and also anticipate all possible errors, you can mess up your whole system.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I gave up on recovering the files. @jay.sf is there another way to rename files? Maybe a safer way? Although I don't know what you mean by safe. Thank you.

Comment: @WinnieXi See my answer below for a safer option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is actually nice and works well. The problem is that there might be an unexpected error and there is no undo option. I probably would use a `function` that by default doesn't execute the renaming but throws the new file name instead. So you are able to check thoroughly before you arm the function.

```
fun <- function(x, run=FALSE) {
  df <- read.csv(x)
  reporter <- tolower(unique(df$Reporter.ISO))
  v <- versions[unique(df$Classification)]
  to <- paste0("imports_2007_", reporter, "_hs6_v", v, ".csv")
  if (run) {
    file.rename(x, to)
  } else {
    return(to)
  }
}

## setup
setwd('~/testdir')
versions <- c(H0="1992", H1="1996", H2="2002", H3="2007", H4="2012", H5="2017", H6="2022")
files <- list.files()
```

Looping the function over the file names in an `sapply` gives a vector of the new file names named by the old file names. It doesn't execute the renaming by default. Now run some tests until you're convinced it will be right.

```
test <- sapply(files, fun)
test
# file1.csv                      file2.csv 
# "imports_2007_1_hs6_v1992.csv" "imports_2007_2_hs6_v1996.csv" 
# file3.csv                      file4.csv 
# "imports_2007_3_hs6_v2002.csv" "imports_2007_4_hs6_v2007.csv" 
# file5.csv                      file6.csv 
# "imports_2007_5_hs6_v2012.csv" "imports_2007_6_hs6_v2017.csv" 
# file7.csv 
# "imports_2007_7_hs6_v2022.csv" 

any(duplicated(test))  ## example, test if there are duplicates
# [1] FALSE

list.files()  ## see file names are not changed
# [1] "file1.csv" "file2.csv" "file3.csv" "file4.csv" "file5.csv"
# [6] "file6.csv" "file7.csv"
```

If you set `run=TRUE` you arm the function and renaming is executed.

```
sapply(files, fun, run=TRUE)

list.files()  ## now they are changed
# [1] "imports_2007_1_hs6_v1992.csv" "imports_2007_2_hs6_v1996.csv"
# [3] "imports_2007_3_hs6_v2002.csv" "imports_2007_4_hs6_v2007.csv"
# [5] "imports_2007_5_hs6_v2012.csv" "imports_2007_6_hs6_v2017.csv"
# [7] "imports_2007_7_hs6_v2022.csv"
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- list(file1 = structure(list(X = 1:3, x = 1:3, Classification = c("H0", 
"H0", "H0"), Reporter.ISO = c(1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), file2 = structure(list(X = 1:3, x = 1:3, Classification = c("H1", 
"H1", "H1"), Reporter.ISO = c(2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), file3 = structure(list(X = 1:3, x = 1:3, Classification = c("H2", 
"H2", "H2"), Reporter.ISO = c(3L, 3L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), file4 = structure(list(X = 1:3, x = 1:3, Classification = c("H3", 
"H3", "H3"), Reporter.ISO = c(4L, 4L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), file5 = structure(list(X = 1:3, x = 1:3, Classification = c("H4", 
"H4", "H4"), Reporter.ISO = c(5L, 5L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), file6 = structure(list(X = 1:3, x = 1:3, Classification = c("H5", 
"H5", "H5"), Reporter.ISO = c(6L, 6L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), file7 = structure(list(X = 1:3, x = 1:3, Classification = c("H6", 
"H6", "H6"), Reporter.ISO = c(7L, 7L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)))

setwd('~/testdir')
lapply(names(dat), \(x) write.csv(dat[[x]], paste0(x, '.csv')))
```

Comment: Wow. What a thorough explanation. I can't thank you enough.